# How to search omitting whitespace on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

Elasticsearch noob here trying to understand something

I have this query

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": "pokemon.name",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "_name": "name-match",
            "type": "phrase",
            "fields": ["pokemon.name"],
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "pika"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "_name": "weight-match",
            "type": "most_fields",
            // I use multi_match because I'm not sure how can I change it to match
            "fields": ["pokemon.weight"],
            "query": "10kg"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is `pokemon.weight` has a space between the value and the unit `10 Kg`. So I need to ignore the whitespace in order to match with `10kg`

I've tried to change the tokenizer, sadly it can decide where to split but not to remove a character. Anyway I don't know how to use it and the documentation isn't very helpful, explains the theory but not how to use it.

Thanks! Any learning resource will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom analyzer with a `char filter`. where you will replace a `space` char with an `empty` char, so that tokens generated in your case `10` and `g`, becomes `10g`. I tried it locally and working fine for me.

**Bonus links for understanding how [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) works in ES and example of the custom analyzer with [char filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html).**

Below is my custom analyzer to achieve required tokens:-

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "\\u0020=>"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now using the same analyzer, it generated below token, which I confirmed using [analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) api.

Endpoint :- http://{{your_hostname}}:9500/{{your_index_name}}/_analyzer

body :-

```
{
    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
    "text" : "10 g"
}
```

Result :-

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "10g",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This has to be used very carefully and only on very selected fields, if you notice there is only one token that gets generated for long text.

Comment: @Kamal , yeah as it removes all the spaces, thanks for giving the proactive advise :-)

Comment: Thank you! that was really helpful :)